# why Python doesn't convert \n to newline when queried from Sqlite?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, pyqt

I want to query from Sqlite and contains \n and I expect python converts it to newline but it doesn't. and I also changed \n to \n in the database but still can't be converted.

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT test FROM table_name ''')
for row in cursor:
        self.ui.textEdit.append(row[0])
        # or 
        print row[0]
```

I also tried `unicode(row[0])` and not working. I am surprised there is no an easy solution for this in the web.

Comment: If it's a literal '\n', it wont.

Comment: @jayanth ok but even it won't work with \\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither SQLite nor Python convert characters in strings (except for `\` escapes in a Python string written in the source code).
Newlines work correctly if you handle them correctly:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c = db.cursor()
>>> c.execute('create table t(x)')
>>> c.execute("insert into t values ('x\ny')")
>>> c.execute("insert into t values ('x\\ny')")
>>> c.execute("select * from t")
>>> for row in c:
...   print row[0]
...
x
y
x\ny
```